# fix iframe position

Tags: html, css

I have a form on the top of a page with a height of 20-30px and a width of 100%. Below there's an iframe with a height of 100% and a width of 100%. But this brings a scroll, because the height of the page is out of the bounds.

How do I make both fit 100% without having a scroll?

P.S I know changing the height to 83% of the iframe will make it work, but only for chrome, for IE it is different story...

Comment: Is your css set: html, body {height: 100%;} ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `<iframe>` to have `position:absolute` in position to the form:

```
 form{
      width:100%;height:30px;
 }
 iframe{
      width:100%;position:absolute;top:30px;bottom:0px;
 }
```

Comment: And how are you so sure the form will be 30px? In chrome it has one size, in IE it is different.

Comment: Well, that's a bad thing if it looks one way in one browser and totally different in another. If you set the form's height to be 30px  as shown in my answer, then it will render the same height across all browsers.